Actualizar listas al hacer un post o delete desde el frontend
tengo la siguiente consulta.
Tengo una aplicacion web con REACT que muestra las diferentes operaciones que tiene un usuario en una cuenta. El usuario puede agregar nuevas operaciones o eliminar las existentes.
Al momento de agregar o eliminar una operacion es necesario actualizar la lista de operaciones que se esta mostrando. Veo dos opciones para realizar esta actualizacion, la primera seria volver a realizar un GET a la RestApi y la segunda, luego de hacer el cambio, agregarlo localmente a mi estructura.
La pregunta es cual es la forma correcta de realizarlo si la app esta en produccion? Veo mas eficiente la segunda opcion ya que realiza menos consultas a la api pero no se si puede haber riesgo de inconsistencia de datos.
Dejo parte del codigo para que se entienda mejor. Esta es la parte del codigo encargada de mostrar los elementos:
const [operationsList, setOperationList] = useState([])
const getItems = async () => {
  try{
    const response = await AccountOperationService.list(id, accountId, token)
    setOperationList(response)
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getItems()
},[])
 return(
 <button onClick={() => addOperation()>Add</button
 {
    operationsList.map((item) => (
        <tr>
            <td>{item.date}</td>
            <td>{item.name}</td>
            <td>{item.description}</td>
            <td>{item.amount}</td>
        </tr>
    ))
}

)
Entonces estas serian las dos opciones para realizar la funcion de add:
Opcion 1
const addOperation= async (e) =>{
    try {
        const id = localStorage.getItem('userId')
        const body = {accountId:accountId,name:name,description:description,amount:amount,date:date,type:operationType}
        const response = await AccountOperationService.add(id, body);
        getItems() // Vuelvo a llamar a la funcion para que se actualize el operation list
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

Opcion 2
const addOperation= async (e) =>{
    try {
        const id = localStorage.getItem('userId')
        const body = {accountId:accountId,name:name,description:description,amount:amount,date:date,type:operationType}
        const response = await AccountOperationService.add(id, body);
        setOperationList(operationList => [...operationList, response]) //Se setea de forma local el operationList luego que se actualizo la base de datos
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Las preguntas basadas en opiniones suelen terminar cerradas, porque justamente vas a recibir opiniones a favor de las dos... y todas van a tener razon...

Puedes hacer algo llamado "Actualizaciones optimistas". Basicamente, actualizas el estado (eliminas o agregas en este caso, lo que necesites) y mientras haces eso, haces la operación con la API, de tal forma que eso genera una respuesta que te dice si lo dejas o lo cambias.
Recuerda atajar los problemas con estructuras como Try Catch para evitar renderizar errores
